# Does SVN support some sort of comments in its properties?

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I want to use SVN externals on my projects to include a number of third party plugins. I've found this blog post recommending saving the svn:externals value in a file (called svn.externals) with the destination/source pairs, like this:

```
akismet http://svn.wp-plugins.org/akismet/trunk
all-in-one-seo-pack http://svn.wp-plugins.org/all-in-one-seo-pack/trunk
```

and to use the the `-F` flag to set the property, like so:

```
svn propset svn:externals -F svn.externals
```

I got the above info from [beer planet](http://beerpla.net/2009/06/20/how-to-properly-set-svn-svnexternals-property-in-svn-command-line/).

Now to the quesiton. Does SVN support a comment format allowing me to comment this svn.externals file? I'd like to group the external repositories under `libraries`,  `widgets` and the like. Also, I was thinking to add instructions on how to update this file/property for my fellow developers at the top of the file. Example, assuming the `#` starts a comment:

```
# README: When updating svn:externals
#  1. Update and save this file
#  2. Run 'svn propset svn:externals -F svn.externals
#  3. Commit 'svn ci -m "plugin XXXXXXXX added to svn:externals"'

# wp plugins
wp/content/plugins/akismet http://svn.wp-plugins.org/akismet/trunk
wp/content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack http://svn.wp-plugins.org/all-in-one-seo-pack/trunk

# jquery + plugins
js/jquery http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
# etc etc (this is just a random example of my idea)
```

-

To sum up, my question is, does SVN support some sort of comments in its properties? And if it does, what's the syntax?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the source code \svn\main.c:1124 (version 1.7.1)

```
 "      Lines in externals definitions starting with the '#' character\n"
 "      are considered comments and are ignored.\n"
```

Comment: Two answers within an hour after nearly a year, what's that about?
Anyway thanks, it seems my own hypothetical file format actually works. I asked the question when I had just started using SVN and didn't dare just testing it on the company's repo.

Comment: i'm not sure. somehow this question ended up the front page on the day i answered it.

Comment: "svnadmin create /tmp/repo" "svn co file:///tmp/repo ." to experiment with a local repository.

Comment: The latest version has moved the location of this comment to Line 1589 of`subversion/trunk/subversion/svn/svn.c` [see source](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/svn/svn.c#:~:text=Lines%20starting%20with%20a%20%27%23%27%20character%20are%20ignored)

Answer (score 0):

Using # works for comments, as per

http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@subversion.apache.org/msg00189.html

I've tested this with 1.6.12, at least.